# Get the accordion style for non-accordion elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am completely new in jQuery UI's CSS styles so please bear with me.

I have to make a list of contact people.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">George Foo</a></h3>
    <div>
        some information
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Michelle Bar</a></h3>
    <div>
        some information
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Bill Wind</a></h3>
    <div>
        some information
    </div>
</div>
```

At first, I thought using the accordion style. However, usage showed me that opening more than one contact might be interesting as well. So I read the note on the bottom of the [accordion page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) to use this instead of accordion:

```
From page:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.accordion .head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
}).next().hide();
});
```

My problem is that it doesn't look like accordion (smoothness style). I suppose I am not putting the *accordion* and *head* class at the right place, but as of now the names look like default links.
How can I have the same look for the headers as the accordion effect, without using accordion?
I tried searching around but from what I found that specific problem is not much discussed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion a").click(function() {
    $(this).next.slideToggle();
    return false;
  }).next().hide();
});
```

If you want to add styles to the links that are accordionified (is that a word?), try something like:

```
$("#accordion a").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('someClass').removeClass('someOtherClass');
});
```

If you're looking to discover exactly what styles accordion applies to the links, take a look at an implementation of it on another site, and inspect the elements with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the classes used, then you can link in that stylesheet..

Comment: It works as well but my links still have the default *look* for those href. I would like to have the same look the accordion has.   The .accordion() function applies specific CSS styles on the target, which makes everything pretty -- but what if I want those styles without using accordion? This is where I'm stuck, it's merely about looks and I don't know what to modify to imitate the stylesheet .accordion() uses.

Comment: Edited my post to try answer your question better - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I am getting closer.  
I checked with FireBug as you suggested and there are a load of things changing during clicks. I wish there was an easier way to imitate accorion's look, but I'll have to add my own CSS then.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make them have the accordion style you can inspect the classes jQuery UI adds to an actual accordion e.g. with a tool like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843). In the end it probably looks like this:

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-widget-content padding ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion ui-widget">
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        <a href="#">George Foo</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        some information
    </div>
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        <a href="#">Michelle Bar</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        some information
    </div>
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        <a href="#">Bill Wind</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        some information
    </div>
</div>
```

If you just want to change the default behaviour of an existing accordion it might be easier to add your functionality there instead of rebuilding the whole thing.